# Using the HttpUtility in a Xamarin forms pcl project

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am trying to use the HttpUtility in my Xamarin forms application. I have a Pcl project. Is this not possible? I tried to add the system.web namespace but no luck. Please assist. How can I get this to work.

```
string postString = String.Format("username={0}&password={1}&grant_type=password", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(username), HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(password));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it should be `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode`

**EDIT - 1**

As per your code sample, I believe you are targeting url encoding - you should use `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode`; but if you specifically want to use html-encoding, `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode` is also available in same namespace.

*Sample code*

```
using System.Net;

string postString = String.Format("username={0}&password={1}&grant_type=password", 
       WebUtility.UrlEncode(username), 
       WebUtility.UrlEncode(password));
```

Comment: What do I add from Nuget package. I am using visual studio for Mac.

Comment: As far as I am aware no nuget package needed

Comment: So how do I use this from the code I pasted? I don't get it

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same issue and adding a reference to the 'System.Net.Http' did the trick for me.